# Remove duplicate elements from a tcl List

Tags: list, tcl

I have a list variable $a which has below as value.

```
{1|Katy|347689    2|Jerry|467841  1|Katy|987654}
```

I am trying to remove duplicated on the basis of

```
1|Katy avoiding the userid available at last.
```

Expected output should be.

```
{1|Katy|347689 2|Jerry|467841}
```

I tried using lsort -unique option. Seems like this does not work properly in my case.

```
set uniqueElement [lsort -unique $a]
```

Also ,just for illustrative purpose the list values are shown as having 3 values. I have more than 500 in the same format. I am trying to remove duplicates on the basis of 1|Katy while avoiding the userid.
Can suggest any other way I can resolve this to remove duplicates in this format for a list?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit tricky as you have parts that are to be ignored when deduplicating. Because of that, `lsort -unique` is *not* the right tool. Instead, you want to use a dictionary.

```
# Identify the values that each key maps to
set d {}
foreach entry $inputList {
    # Alternatively, use regular expressions to do the entry parsing
    set value [join [lassign [split $entry "|"] a b] "|"]
    set key [string cat $a "|" $b]

    dict lappend d $key $value
}

# Build the output list using the first value each key maps to
set outputList {}
dict for {key values} $d {
    lappend outputList [string cat $key "|" [lindex $values 0]]
}
```

That makes `outputList` hold the value you are seeking. (You don't need to use `string cat`, but I think it makes the code clearer in this case.)

Comment: I am restricted to version 8.5. dict lappend won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `lsort -unique` by manipulating your initial list beforehand:

```tk
    set new_format_list [join [split $a "|"] ]
    set new_format_sorted_list [lsort -unique -stride 3 $new_format_list]
    foreach {el1 el2 el3} $new_format_sorted_list  {
      lappend newlist "$el1|$el2|$el3"
    }
    puts "$newlist"
```

1. The variable `new_format_list` is now a flat list of all elements of your entry list (here, 9 elements). The `|` have been used to split the element of your initial list.
2. The variable `new_format_sorted_list`  actually remove duplicate. Stride 3 means elements of the list will be check 3 by 3. Only the 1st of 3 is used for comparison.
3. The `foreach` is used to create a list with the same format that is used in entry. `lappend` is able to create variable if it doen't exist.
4. check the result

Normally, you should get what you want.

*Edit based on nurdglaw pertinent comment*

```tcl
# entry list
set original_list {1|Katy|347689    2|Jerry|467841  1|Katy|987654}

set temp_list [join [split $original_list "|"] ]

# dirty method
# separate the third element from the first two 
# then the string of the first two elements is the id for uniqueness
foreach {l1 l2 l3} $temp_list {
    append new_format_list "$l1|$l2 $l3 " ;# use string to make a tcl list
    #the space at this end is mandatory
} 
set new_format_sorted_list [lsort -unique -stride 2 $new_format_list]

foreach {el1 el2} $new_format_sorted_list  {
  lappend cleanlist "$el1|$el2"
}
puts "$cleanlist"
```

Comment: While this answer works ok for the OP's example data, I'm not sure whether it will solve the problem he originally posed. What if the input data were {1|Katy|347689 1|Jerry|467841 1|Katy|987654}? I think your code will discard the 1|Jerry467841 entry. It seems fairly clear that the OP only wants to ignore the third part of the entries when looking for possible duplicates - your code ignores the second part as well.

Comment: you are right, i didn't get  the OP want to keep the entries based on the first 2 values